# $R$ is a prime right Goldie ring which contains a minimal right ideal. Show that $R$ must be a simple Artinian ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, rngs, artinian

$R$ (1 is not assumed to be in $R$) is a prime right Goldie ring (finite dimensional and ACC on right annihilators) which contains a minimal right ideal. Show that $R$ must be a simple Artinian ring.

This appeared in a past paper, the first 2 parts which I managed to prove were "Every essential right ideal of a semi-prime right Goldie ring contains a regular element" and "Every non-zero ideal of a prime ring must be essential as a right ideal". There is also an extra hint that I might have to use Artin-Wedderburn.

I've been trying (and failing) to find a way to use these results since I can't assume (or prove that) the minimal right ideal is an ideal (to use the previous result). I also have that the minimal ideal is of the form $eR$ where $e$ is idempotent, but I feel like i'm barking up the wrong tree. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* identity is not assumed? It is very unusual in this context to talk about rngs. If you have identity, then your answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163211/a-prime-ring-whose-socle-is-nonzero-and-of-finite-length-is-simple-artinian/2165849#2165849).

Comment: At times like this I wish I could remember if Jacobson proved his density theorem for rngs. Using the linked question it's not hard to prove $R$ is a submodule of a direct sum of simple modules, but again I don't recall if the characterization of semisimple rings holds up without explicitly saying there is an identity.

Comment: You can't prove the minimal right ideal is an ideal because that is obviously not necessary. Just look at square matrix rings over fields. A better idea would be to look at the sum of all right ideals isomorphic to it, which *is* an ideal. Immediately you know the ring has an essential right socle, which must be finitely generated by your assumption it is right Goldie...

Comment: The question about the density theorem for rngs has [come up before](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2106080/29335)

Comment: @rschwieb In my course, Artinian rings are assumed to have 1, but Noetherian rings are not, but here we have ACC not to mention only on right annihilators. I also double checked the defs for Goldie ring, but that does not mention 1 either. Also in the exam it always specifies when 1 is included http://i.imgur.com/njeqoL4.png for example.

Comment: I also didn't think of using the socle, it feels like the right track and i'll see if it works.

Comment: I've found a chain of reasoning that suggests the ring might have 1. Via Goldie's theorem, "$R$ is a prime right Goldie ring iff $R$ has a simple right quotient ring (which has 1 by def)". But this proof relies on Ore's theorem to prove the quotient ring exists, "$R$ is a ring with at least one regular element, let $S$ be the set of all regular elements of $R$, then $R$ has the right Ore condition on $S$ iff $R$ has a right quotient ring." But when I look at the proof of Ore's I can't see where the existence of 1 is proven. (Proof was at the end of the course, rushed and non-examinable).

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this is true: if $R$ is a finite direct sum of $R/M$'s where the $M$'s are maximal *modular* right ideals, then $R$ has identity." There is an obvious candidate but whether or not it works is unclear to me.

Comment: Recently I read something that suggests that Herstein's *Noncommutative rings* proves that a semisimple artinian rng has identity. I'd like to check it out to see if it meshes with what we've said above. If so, then we have a complete proof without assuming identity.

Comment: @rschwieb It's true I believe, how it was proved in my course, semisimple artinian rng $R$ has an idempotent $e$ st $R=eR=Re$ which must be the identity. I'm not sure how this links up though.

Comment: Well... I explained how $R$ embeds in a finite direct sum of simple modules... so it is semisimple! Unless that is no the definition of semisimple you had in the course?

Comment: @rschwieb We define a r(i)ng to be semisimple Artinian if it has no non-zero nilpotent right ideals and DCC on right ideals. And I have that a ss Artinian r(i)ng has identity.

We also know that $R$ is ss Artinian iff $R$ has 1 and $R_R$ is completely reducible.

So I think I still have to prove 1 is in the ring even if it's a finite direct sum of simple modules.

Comment: I see. I'll let you know what my review of the literature uncovers, when it happens.

Comment: @rschwieb My lecturer got back to me and told me the answer below if you were interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E(R)$ be the right socle of $R$. $E(R)$ is an ideal of $R$, so it is essential as a right ideal and therefore contains a regular element, $c$ say.

$R$ is isomorphic to $cR$, via the isomorphism $r\rightarrow cr$. (If $cr=0$ then $r(c)=0$ implies $r=0$, injective. Surjective obvious.)

$cR$ is inside $E(R)$, so it is completely reducible, therefore $R$ is completely reducible. R is then a direct sum of irreducible submodules, this direct sum is finite as $R$ is Goldie. Therefore $R$ is right Artinian. Prime right Artinian rings are simple.

Comment: There are a lot of strange things about what you've written that I don't understand.  *"$cR$ is inside $E(R)$, so it is completely reducible, therefore $R$ is completely reducible."* Well if that logic seems valid to you... $R$ is inside $E(R)$ from the beginning, so what is the point of $cR$?

Comment: And I'm not sure why being contained in $E(R)$ would imply $R$ is completely reducible. (It might be very simple and I just don't know the argument.)  But certainly you can take whatever random non-completely-reducible module $M$ that you like and $E(M)$ contains it and it doesn't prove the complete reducibility of $M$.

Comment: I thought you were not satisfied by the result of proving $R$ is completely reducible. I will write out the strategy that I mentioned above as a solution, then.

Comment: @rschwieb $c\in E(R)$ implies $cR\subset E(R)$ as $E(R)$ is an ideal. Otherwise i'm not sure why $R$ would be inside $E(R)$?
We define a module to be completely reducible if it is a sum of (not necessarily direct but equivalent) irreducible submodules and $E(R)$ is a sum of irreducible submodules and we have proven $R=E(R)$.

Comment: oh, there has been some misunderstanding... $E(R)$ is standard notation for the injective envelope of $R$. What ideal do you mean? Oh must be the right socle?  (Very strange choice of notation) that certainly is an interesting way to get a copy of $R$ in the socle :)

Comment: yeah, I wasn't aware of the other uses of $E(R)$, we use that notation in our course.

Answer (score 0):

By primeness of $R$, the minimal right ideal of $R$ must be faithful, so the ring is actually right primitive, and its Jacobson radical is zero.

There exists, then, a collection of maximal regular right ideals $\{T_i\mid i\in I\}$ such that $J(R)=\cap T_i=\{0\}$. This allows the natural embedding of $R_R\hookrightarrow\prod_{i\in I} R/M_i$.

Going back to the assumptions, we know that $soc(R_R)$ is an essential right ideal of $R$. Since it is Goldie, the semisimple module $soc(R_R)$ is finitely generated. It's well known that if $R$ has a finitely generated essential right socle, then it is finitely cogenerated as a module. The embedding $R_R\hookrightarrow\prod_{i\in I} R/M_i$ therefore restricts to a finite subset $F$ so that $R_R\hookrightarrow\prod_{i\in F} R/M_i$.

But $\prod_{i\in F} R/M_i=\bigoplus_{i\in F}R/M_i$, so that $R$ is embedded in this finitely generated completely reducible module, and therefore is completely reducible itself, hence Artinian.

According to your notes, this prime Artinian ring has identity and is a simple Artinian ring by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem.

Comment: At least, I *think* everything here works in rings without identity. It is so rare to have to check...